# How to present list of names in Presenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, presenter

I have my custom presenter

```
class ShiftPresenter
  def initialize(shift, template)
    @shift = shift
    @template = template
  end

  def h
    @template
  end

  def users_list
    logs = ShiftLog.by_shift(@shift)
    names = logs.map do |log|
      log.cardiologist.name
    end
    h.content_tag :div, names unless names.empty?
  end
end
```

and `#index` view

```
- present shift do |shift_presenter|
  = shift_presenter.user_list
```

How to present users names using `li` instead of ['tom', 'jerry']

Comment: Oh, I see. Well try to change `h.content_tag :div, names unless names.empty?` into `h.content_tag :div, names.map{|str| '<li>' + str + '</li>'}.join unless names.empty?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this to your presenter method:

```
def users_list
  logs = ShiftLog.by_shift(@shift)
  names = logs.map(&:cardiologist).map(&:name)#.compact.uniq # you can add this if you want
  h.content_tag :div do
    h.content_tag :ul do
      ul_content = ''.html_safe
      names.each do |name|
        ul_content << h.content_tag :li, name
      end
      ul_content
    end
  end
```

The thing is it works as block with the return statement: the last used/returned object will be put inside the content_tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns nothing

Comment: still the same problem, works only when I am ``return names``

Comment: Have you seen that you call `shift_presenter.user_list` and you implemented the `users_list` method (note the plural here). Maybe a typo?

Comment: maybe I should move that logic to model?

Comment: No no no, leave it in your presenter (very nice to see someone using this by the way!). Okay I found out what was wrong, I update my answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap each element of `names` in `users_list` method into `<li>` tag and join them in a string. To do this you need to change this line:

```
h.content_tag :div, names unless names.empty?
```

into this:

```
h.content_tag :div, names.map{|str| '<li>' + str + '</li>'}.join unless names.empty?
```